# Possible Memory Leak after Windows Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, drivers, memory-leaks, windows-10-v1809, norton-360

I am currently running Windows 10 v1809 Pro using an Intel i5-8250U processor and 8GB SODIMM DDR4 RAM @ 2400 MHz

I updated to v1809 from v1803 back in December, and since then, I've noticed that my Memory used at idle and my paged/non-paged pool is significantly more than it used to be, particularly after my computer has been running for awhile.

Prior to the update, my system would idle at about 33% Memory usage, but after awhile it tends to idle at 35% and steadily creeps up to 38-41% without anything open, assuming I just do light web browsing. If I do things like run my antivirus, or a decent bit of troubleshooting, it'll idle at closer to 45%. I don't recall what my paged/non-paged used to be, but I keep seeing that ~300mb is supposed to be normal for non-paged, and mine is usually about 750-800mb, but went as high as sitting at 945mb after running Malwarebytes, and ScanHealth/RestoreHealth in cmd, while paged was sitting at 859 until I restarted. Neither seemed to be ticking down at all when left alone; if anything, they seem to very slowly be ticking up, indefinitely.

I've been trying to figure out the source of the change/problem, but I'm not exactly computer savvy.

I've tried using PoolMon, and from what I can make sense of, the largest non-paged thing listed was IAStor, which I do not know where to update the driver for (if it has one). Also, the Empty Standby List thing in RamMap (which I'd been told to try as a sort of reset button) didn't work, either.

I've also been told to check the commit sizes/NP pool in Task Manager's Details tab, in which my highest Commit size and NP pool come from Norton 360 at 387,852k and 537k, respectively. I've never had an issue with Norton before in all the 10 or more years I've used it. It says it's up to date. I'm not sure if the upgrade to v1809 somehow glitched something and I should reinstall it, or if it is just a symptom of some other issue.

I've also tried to see if it was something to do with my Network Data Usage Monitor (I keep seeing it referred to as NDU), as I've seen that be listed as a culprit (though usually with Killer as the device, whereas I have Intel as best I can see) particularly since "Network" (in the form of Wi-Fi) doesn't show in my Task Manager's Performance tab (nor does it show usage in Processes, even though the status column is there) after my computer has been running for some time. I ran the diagnostic for it in Windows, and it didn't see anything. Network still didn't show in my Performance tab so I don't think it did anything, and I don't know what else to do to pursue this avenue. I restarted about 10 days ago I have been able see it since, though I don't know if it's a fluke or just has yet to glitch again as I had changed nothing from before, so I don't know what changed.

Has anyone else had this issue? Is it NDU, Norton, or something else? And more importantly, how do I resolve it?

Comment: You need to tell us how much RAM you have on your PC, and of what type (DDR3, DDR4, etc...). Is it a laptop or desktop? Motherboard, peripherals, etc...? This said, is it such a big deal for you that your PC uses a little more memory now than before the upgrade/update? Maybe it's indexing, and will return to normal when done. Tell us more about your hardware config, please.

Comment: Also, are you getting the page pool statistics from Task Manager? That is not necessarily an accurate depiction of the page pool, you might want to check out RAMMap from the Sysinternals toolkit. That being said, paging is not necessarily a bad thing, it becomes a performance issue when the system has to page to your hard drive (i.e., a hard fault). You can view the hard faults/sec in the Resource Monitor tool. If I am remembering correctly, consistent hard faults/sec over 5 might indicate you are running out of memory (keyword being consistent).

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot the type; it is DDR4. 8gb, as mentioned at the top. What else did I forget that you need?

Also the fact that I'm using a decent bit of it isn't really my concern; rather I am concerned about the fact that its usage at rest, with nothing open, keeps slowly increasing the longer my computer is on, especially when it had not done so before (Nor has any computer I have owned in recent memory). As far as I can tell, the memory never gets "released" like it used to. Before upgrading, it did briefly increase the load, but slowly went back down over time. It no longer does so.

Comment: One thing you can try that's pretty inoccuous and may, or may not, change your RAM usage, is increase the RAM threshold for svchost process splitting. That way, your svchost will be less numerous, and you should notice a decrease in both CPU and RAM usage, but not by a wide margin. Open Registry, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control, and in the right pane, double-click the SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB entry to give it a 8388608 value. That's slightly above your installed RAM, and should suffice to reduce svchost processes. Save, restart, and tell us how you fare.

Comment: EDIT: if SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB doesn't exist (doubtful, but you never know), create a new DWORD by that name and give it the value I indicated in my previous comment, save and restart.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I am not the most computer savvy person, and all I know of Registry is that it involves fundamental changes to the computer and I am usually advised not to touch it. So, just to ensure I know what I'm doing/getting into, what exactly does this change do/risk? And would it be sufficient to stop a memory leak (as it appears this is)? Sorry to sound so skeptical, but I cannot replace this computer and do not have an alternative for it, so I want to ensure that I take all of the necessary precautions